# Is it possible to configure Tailwindcss typography for multiple fonts by language?

Tags: fonts, tailwind-css, multilingual

My Tailwindcss / nextjs project uses @tailwindcss/typography package and has a google font defined. It loads and works fine.

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        'main-sans': ["Lexend Deca", "sans-serif"]
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Then in various css modules classes are defined to include the font using @apply. Here is one example:

```
.headerBig {
  @apply text-[22px] leading-[26px] font-main-sans font-[500];
}
```

The problem now is we need to support many languages and many require different fonts. For example, Lexend Deca doesn't support Japanese.  We need to use Noto Sans JP font when the user selects Japanese and the page html lang attribute changes to lang="ja-JP".

In vanilla css this task is trivial using the "lang" attribute selector:

```
html[lang="ja-JP"] body{ font-family: "Noto Sans JP" }
```

I know we can also just not use Tailwindcss @apply for the font family. But it will be a shame because the classes that depend on it are all over our code.

Is there any way to override a Tailwindcss theme fontFamily definition based on the html lang attribute?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a solution which is not ideal, but works.

Add the Japanese version of the font to the theme:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        'main-sans': ["Lexend Deca", "sans-serif"],
        'main-sans-jp': ["Noto Sans JP", "Noto Sans", "sans-serif"],
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Then in css modules use lang selector to override:

```
.headerBig {
  @apply text-[22px] leading-[26px] font-main-sans font-[500];
}

html[lang="ja-JP"] {
  .headerBig {
    @apply text-[22px] leading-[26px] font-main-sans-jp font-[500];  
  }
}
```